# Is it possible to restrict XSD attributes to follow a numerical order?

Tags: xml, xsd

For example, if I have following XML document:

```
<course name="math">
  <grade attempt="1">F</grade>
  <grade attempt="2">F</grade>
  <grade attempt="3">B</grade>
</course>
```

How could I use XSD to validate that the attribute "attempt" only has a value of 2 if there is a 1 present, and a value of 3 if there is a 2 present, and so on?

**edit:** to make it clearer, what I need is a possibility to have the first element have the value "1" in the attribute, and each successive sibling has the value increased by one.

Comment: If you are not bound to XSD, you can alternatively use [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/) to perform such validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible but not in XSD 1.0.

**Simplest solution:**  Drop the `@attempt` attribute altogether; it adds nothing.

I suggest you reexamine the goal of enforcing a constraint explicitly that would otherwise come for free if left implied.  Drop the `@attempt` attribute, which only serves to identify the position of the `grade` element in a sequence, and let it be implied by the sequence that no later sequence position can exist without previous positions already existing.

XSD 1.0 cannot help with your request in its original form, and using XSD 1.1 assertions or Schematron or outside code is overkill.  Just drop `@attempt` then you can trivially use XSD 1.0, and application development will be simplified as well.  You can generate the attempt number anywhere it's needed based on sequence position.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This was actually a college task, and I think he professor is trying to trick us into trying to solve it (since we have to use XSD 1.0). I wouldn't put it past him.

Answer (score 1):

You've suggested two possible constraints you want to enforce:

(a) "follow a numerical order". I would read that as saying that on each element, the value of @attempt must be greater than (not necessarily greater by one) than the previous @attempt. For example 1,2,4 is legal but 1,4,2 is not.

(b) "only has a value of 2 if there is a 1 present". I would read that as saying that the set of attempt values form a dense numeric sequence, not necessarily ordered. For example the sequence 3,1,2 would be acceptable, but 4,1,2 would not.

Which is it? We can't help you code up the constraint if your description of it is so vague and ambiguous.

Either way, it's easy enough to describe the constraint using XSD 1.1 assertions once we know what the constraint really is.

UPDATE

You say the rule is that the @attempt values should strictly be 1, 2, 3, etc. In that case a suitable assertion might be

```
every $g in grade satisfies $g/@attempt eq count($g/preceding-sibling::grade)+1]
```

Comment: I'm sorry for being ambiguous, what I meant was a combination of both possibilities you mention. Also, quite literally, that the first element has the value "1" as attribute, and all successive siblings have the value increased by one.

Comment: Added to the answer based on new information supplied.